# Store crawled links in array, then calling a function to scrape those contents

Tags: arrays, ruby, web-crawler, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm on a shop page with multiple articles shown. I can already see all article links which I got with 'links_with'. Now I want to crawl the content on the article pages within a new function. I can get there but then I only have one address and I want to crawl multiple pages with the content. Is there a way to solve this with an array and someloops? I'm new to Ruby and I could not solve this for myself.

```
def self.configureCrawler(page_URL)
  agent = Mechanize.new
  page = agent.get(page_URL)

  article_links = page.links_with(href: %r{.*/p/}) #all links with /p/ in address

  article_links.uniq { |link| link.uri }.each do |link| #no double entries
    link.click
    @target_URL = page.uri + link.uri #full url
    puts "#{@target_URL}"
  end

  startCrawler(@target_URL)
end


def self.startCrawler(article_URL) #the crawling process itself
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(article_URL))

  @id = page.css('CSS STUFF').text.
  @name = page.css('CSS STUFF').text
  @price = page.css('CSS STUFF').text
  #...

  puts "id: #{@id}"
  puts "name: #{@name}"
  puts "price: #{@price}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you can use `map` instead of `each`.
`map` also iterate trough but return value.

Try something like this

```
def self.configureCrawler(page_URL)
  agent = Mechanize.new
  page = agent.get(page_URL)

  article_links = page.links_with(href: %r{.*/p/}) #all links with /p/ in address

  article_links.uniq { |link| link.uri }.map do |link| #no double entries
    link.click
    target_URL = page.uri + link.uri #full url
    puts "#{target_URL}"
    startCrawler target_URL
  end
end
```

This way `self.configureCrawler` will return array of results of `startCrawler` calls.
Also you do not need to use instance variables in `self.startCrawler` (remove `@`).

```
def self.startCrawler(article_URL) #the crawling process itself
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(article_URL))

  id = page.css('CSS STUFF').text.
  name = page.css('CSS STUFF').text
  price = page.css('CSS STUFF').text

  puts "id: #{id}"
  puts "name: #{name}"
  puts "price: #{price}"

  { id: id, name: name, price: price } # do not forget to return value, for example such hash
end
```

Comment: Thank you! But when I'm in the startCrawler method, I only have one (the last) page of the array (when I print article_URL). I want to crawl every page with its content. Where do I have to start with the loop?

Comment: It can not be like this. `startCrawler` will be called with every element of `article_links` after `uniq`.